# printing a variable's value and a string together

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to display the output **hello 3**. How can i achieve this with **Serial.print()** method defined in **SoftwareSerial.h** library. I have the following code.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int a = 3;
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.print("hello"+a);
}

void loop(){


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is with multiple invocations. That way you don't have to worry about type conversion.

```
Serial.print("hello");
Serial.print(a);
```

Comment: Ok thank for your replay, but is there any other way?@ignacio

Comment: Sure, lots of ways. But they're slow and clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

```
void setup(){

    Serial.begin(9600);
    string somestring = "hello" + " " + "3";
    Serial.print(somestring);
}
```

Comment: I dont want the ** 3** to be printed directly, i want it via the variable **a**.